# How to override template files in a module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, template, overrides

I have two template files that I need to override in a custom module. Those files are

```
app/design/frontend/<current-theme>/template/catalogue/category/view.phtml 
app/design/frontend/<your-theme>/template/catalogue/product/view.phtml
```

Since I'm very new to Magento I have no idea of how to do that. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Put the below code in your custom extension layout file:

> app/design/frontend//template/catalogue/category/view.phtml

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/catalog/category/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>    
</catalog_category_view>
```

> app/design/frontend//template/catalogue/product/view.phtml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>custom/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Hi @MageComp. Thank you for the answer. But still I got few things to clarify. What do you mean by the custom extension layout file?

Comment: And where should I put the new template files in my custom module?

Comment: In your custom extension you have frontend path like this:
app/design/frontend/[Theme]/layout/extension.xml
app/design/frontend/[Theme]/template/extensionfolder